# Use FFmpeg to calculate Optical Flow magnitude

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, opencv, opticalflow, python

I'm trying to use `FFmpeg` to calculate the total optical flow value (or a motion value) in a short video. Is there a command to do that? Would be open to any alternative approach as well, if it is faster.

I'm currently using `Python` and `openCV` to do that:

```
def getOpticalMag(prev_image, curr_image):

    prev_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(prev_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    curr_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(curr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_image_gray, curr_image_gray, flow=None,
                                        pyr_scale=0.5, levels=1, winsize=15,
                                        iterations=2,
                                        poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.1, flags=0)
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])

    return np.mean(mag)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to extract the motion vector directly from the encoded video stream. FFmpeg does not provide an interface for that. This git https://github.com/jishnujayakumar/MV-Tractus could be interesting.

On the other hand since you are looking for the average motion. You may resize (downsample by factor 2 or 4) the input images and/or use a faster method like DIS flow. Another optimization strategy would be to compute motion vectors for a very sparse grid by using pyramidal Lucas Kanade method.